# My ArrayList size becomes zero(0) after calling function. where is my error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to filter recyclerView item using editText. But whenever I type something, my arrayList size becomes zero(0). I am unable to find the reason behind this.
Array in Constant class:

```
    public static ArrayList<File> searchItem = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<File> filteredMediaList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Method.load_Directory_Files_Search:

```
    public static void load_Directory_Files_Search(File directory){
    File[] fileList=directory.listFiles();
    if(fileList != null && fileList.length>0){
        for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++){
            if(fileList[i].isDirectory()){
                load_Directory_Files_Search(fileList[i]);
            }
            else{
                String name=fileList[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                for(String extension:Constant.videoExtensions){
                    if(name.endsWith(extension)){
                        if(!name.startsWith(".")) {
                            Constant.searchItem.add(fileList[i]);
                            Log.d("searchAdding",String.valueOf(fileList[i]));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my oncreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    editTextSearch = findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    recyclerViewSearch = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSearch);

    allPath = new StoragePath(getExternalFilesDirs(null)).getDeviceStorages();
    for(String path:allPath){
        Log.d("allPath",path);
        File directory=new File(path);
        Method.load_Directory_Files_Search(directory);
    }
    mediaList = Constant.searchItem;
    Constant.filteredMediaList = mediaList;
    Log.d("SearchAllSize",String.valueOf(Constant.searchItem.size())+" | "+
            String.valueOf(Constant.filteredMediaList.size())+" | "+
            String.valueOf(mediaList.size()));

    //initializing everything above
    recyclerViewSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
    recyclerViewAdapterSearch = new RecyclerViewAdapterSearch(this);
    recyclerViewSearch.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterSearch);
    Log.d("SearchAllSize",String.valueOf(Constant.searchItem.size())+" | "+
            String.valueOf(Constant.filteredMediaList.size())+" | "+
            String.valueOf(mediaList.size()));

     //working fine till now
    editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String text = editable.toString();
            filter(text);
        }
    });
```

filter function:

```
public void filter(String text){
    Log.d("searchQueryText",text);

    Constant.filteredMediaList.clear();
    Log.d("SearchFilteredMediaList","clear");

    if(text.length() == 0){
        Constant.filteredMediaList = mediaList;
        Log.d("SearchFilteredMediaList","mediaList");
    }
    else{
        for(File file:mediaList){
            if(file.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                Constant.filteredMediaList.add(file);
                Log.d("SearchFilteredMediaList","adding");
                 
            }
        }
    }
    Log.d("SearchAllSize",String.valueOf(Constant.searchItem.size())+" | "+
            String.valueOf(Constant.filteredMediaList.size())+" | "+
            String.valueOf(mediaList.size()));
    //everything becomes zero here
    recyclerViewAdapterSearch.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

all the arrayList becomes zero after calling filter function.Can anyone help me to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created the 3 lists, I can see as mentioned below:

1. searchItem
2. filteredMediaList
3. mediaList

So once you call the method **"load_Directory_Files_Search"**, it is filling up the list searchItem and memory is allocated.

Now the code:

```
mediaList = Constant.searchItem;
```

over here the same memory allocated to searchItem is referred by mediaList. That being said it means no new memory is created for mediaList. So any changes made to mediaList will affect searchItem as well.

After that, in below mentioned line of code:

```
Constant.filteredMediaList = mediaList;
```

filterMediaList refers to the list which is being pointed by mediaList.

So, now all the 3 lists that you have created searchItem, mediaList and filteredMediaList  all are pointing to same memory. So changes made in any of the list will change all the 3 lists.

Since you have mentioned below mentioned line in filter() method:

```
Constant.filteredMediaList.clear();
```

it clears all the 3 lists, and that's the reason you are getting your list cleared out.

If you don't want other list to get effected while making changes to any other, below is the way to do so

I am writing the code for onCreate method below:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
editTextSearch = findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
recyclerViewSearch = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSearch);

allPath = new StoragePath(getExternalFilesDirs(null)).getDeviceStorages();
for(String path:allPath){
    Log.d("allPath",path);
    File directory=new File(path);
    Method.load_Directory_Files_Search(directory);
}
mediaList = new ArrayList<>(searchItem);
Constant.filteredMediaList = new ArrayList<>(searchItem);
Log.d("SearchAllSize",String.valueOf(Constant.searchItem.size())+" | "+
        String.valueOf(Constant.filteredMediaList.size())+" | "+
        String.valueOf(mediaList.size()));

//initializing everything above
recyclerViewSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
recyclerViewAdapterSearch = new RecyclerViewAdapterSearch(this);
recyclerViewSearch.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterSearch);
Log.d("SearchAllSize",String.valueOf(Constant.searchItem.size())+" | "+
        String.valueOf(Constant.filteredMediaList.size())+" | "+
        String.valueOf(mediaList.size()));

 //working fine till now
editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String text = editable.toString();
        filter(text);
    }
});
```

I hope this solution helps you.